# How to create WCF service which returns file ( .xlsx)

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have xlsx file at server location I just want to return this file to client using WCF service. I don't want to return as stream.

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I believe that if you are not using serialized objects (JSON/XML), streams are the default way to transmit data from a WCF service. Why don't you want to use streams? Is this based on real reasoning or just on a lack of technical understanding?

Comment: As I am using K2 as client application, K2 can not understood the stream response.

Comment: just return the file as a byte array maybe?

Comment: Could you add the code of your WCF service (at least the part that creates the stream)? Assuming K2 understands HTTP I think you will have to use a stream. I believe that the issue ain't K2 not understanding the stream (at the end it's all data anyway), but you not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the *Stream* and set the following headers:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{<name of the file>}\"");
```

The client should know how to handle this.